# Problems with valid pointers operations in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, operations

In K&R, it says the valid pointers operations are assignment of pointes of the same type, adding or subtracting of the same array ......All other pointers arithmetic is illegal.

However, when i read the code of Doubly linked list on Wikipedia, it compares two pointers which points to different nodes of linked list. it confused me a lot.
here is the code

```
    unsigned int DetectCycleinList(void)
    {
        DoublLinkedList* pCurrent = pHead;
        DoublLinkedList* pFast = pCurrent;
        unsigned int cycle = FALSE;
        while ((cycle == false) && pCurrent->pNext != NULL)
        {
            if (!(pFast = pFast->pNext))
            {
                cycle = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (pFast == pCurrent)
            {
                cycle = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (!(pFast = pFast->pNext))
            {
                cycle = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (pFast == pCurrent)
            {
                cycle = true;
                break;
            }
            pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
        }
    }
```

it compares pFast and pCurrent, isn't it illegal.

Comment: It is pointer *arithmetic* that is invalid with pointers to different objects, not equality tests. So if two pointers point in the same array, subtracting them gives the number of array elements between. But it is meaningless if the pointers are to different objetcs, even if they are the same type.

Comment: Sounds like K&R refers to operations on the pointed data, while the Wikipedia article refers (also?) to operations on the pointers themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf), there are no restrictions that two pointers to be compared have to be pointing at elements in the same array.
What are pointed at by `pFast` and `pCurrent` are objects of the same type, so compareing them is legal.

Quote from N1570 6.5.9 Equality operators:

> Constraints
>
> 2 One of the following shall hold:
>   — both operands have arithmetic type;
>   — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
>   — one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or
>   unqualified version of void; or
>   — one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.
>
> [...]
>
> 6 Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers,
>   both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object
>   and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to
>   one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a
>   pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a
>   pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to
>   immediately follow the first array object in the address space.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison may occur between two pointers. For example, if you want to check if a pointer `p` is pointing to the first element of an array `a`:

```
if (p == a)
    /* a points to the start of a */
```

Pointer arithmetic, however, is more restricted.

Comment: There is no same-array restriction on `==` and `!=`.

Comment: @n.m. Fixed the problem